# Missing required argument "[authorizer-properties]" apache kafka simple producer api error

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

While writing kafka producer code inside eclipse I am getting a error mention below,Here I want to write a simple producer code and show the message on kafka console consumer I started the zookeeper and kafka server and created topic perfectly.

Here is code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

public class ProducerTest {
    public static void mian(String ar[]){
        Properties prop=new Properties();

        prop.put("zk.connect","localhost:2181");
        prop.put("serializer.class","kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        prop.put("metadata.broker.list","localhost:9092");

        ProducerConfig config=new ProducerConfig(prop);

        Producer producer=new Producer(config);

        String msg="Sa resta rasta ra";

        producer.send(new KeyedMessage("test",msg));
    }
} 

Missing required argument "[authorizer-properties]"
Option                                  Description                            
----*emphasized text*--                                  -----------                            
--add                                   Indicates you are trying to add ACLs.  
--allow-host <allow-host>               Host from which principals listed in --
                                       allow-principal will have access. If 
                                        you have specified --allow-principal 
                                         then the default for this option     
                                          will be set to * which allows access 
                                          from all hosts.                      
--allow-principal <allow-principal>     principal is in principalType:name     
                                         format. User:* is the wild card
```

Anyone please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Any how I got the solution, I create a different class which contain main method and I remove main method from ProducerTest class and put code into a simple void method by calling a method it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I was getting this error message But now it's gone automatically I just create separated method for connection and call this method from the main method.

```
 public static void main(String ar[]){
 ProducerTest producer=new ProducerTest();
 producer.messageConnetion();
 }

 public void messageConnetion(){
 Properties properties=new Properties();

 properties.put("zk.connect","localhost:8121");
 properties.put("serializer.class","kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
 properties.put("metadata.broker.list","localhost:9092");

 ProducerConfig config=new ProducerConfig(prop);

 Producer<String, String> producer=new Producer<String, String> (config)

 producer.send(new KeyedMessage<String, String> ("test","JaySiyaRam"));
}
```